# How does DBSign use smart card certificates for signatures in a browser-only solution?

Tags: javascript, encryption, browser, smartcard

Recently I've encountered a product (DBSign) that claims to do smartcard signing entirely in the browser without any plugins or java.

As far as I knew this wasn't supported by major browsers / web crypto, but apparently this is working somehow (having used the app it apparently does what it says it does).

Is this now possible in 2019 with webcrypto and I'm just not aware of it? The file is heavily obfuscated and I couldn't make sense out of it.

Comment: One approach used to expose system services to in-browser JavaScript is to run a separate web-server on the local machine that JavaScript sends `fetch`/XHR requests to - this is how Dell's "detect my service-tag" feature works - however DBSign's website says they don't need _any_ client-side installation, so that approach described isn't what they're using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yablargo, I have watched video on DBSign several times. As you are saying "claims to use smartchard" but the solution does not use SmartCard. Video clearly says "this opens door to use global devices and move beyond smartcards..."

This uses Browser SSL/TLS Authentication and [NIST Derived PIV Credentials](https://www.nccoe.nist.gov/projects/building-blocks/piv-credentials)

Thus the Digital Signatures issued by Certifying Authorities (CA) on smart card is not being used here, but some other mechanism.

Hope this resolves your query of "is there any mechanism to access smartcard without Browser Extension or plugin in 2019?" - To me answer seems "No".